# Convert a netCDF file to RData?

Tags: r, netcdf

I've got a `netCDF` data file.The file can be downloaded at:

http://www.nodc.noaa.gov/OC5/WOA09/pr_woa09.html

It's the one called `WOA09 netCDF version`.

I want to use only climatology data (variable 4) and the first depth range [ , ,1] so I've used the code below so far in R. In now want to have the subset called `MyData` in `RData` format.

I want to convert it to `RData` to be able to play around with it in R. I haven't found anything on the internet about doing this, is it even possible? How?

Thank you so much if you can help! And let me know if I haven't given enough info .

```
library(ncdf)

MyFile<-open.ncdf("/home/et1211/wspd.mean.nc")

MyFile$var[[4]]->var4
MyData<-get.var.ncdf(MyFile,var4)

MyData<-MyData[,,1]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. You just `save` the object from R and use .RData as extension:

```
save(MyData, file="myNCDFdata.RData")
```

Or else you can read the ncdf data to an empty workspace, do whatever transformations you need, and  then quit R and click ok to save workspace.